List of "possible publications" at international conferences
I want to apply for a PhD fellowship program abroad and one of the requirements is that I must provide a list of possible publications and presentations at international seminars/conferences, what does this mean?

It actually means if you have come up with a research plan as a part of PhD application, you should have got some research directions. If yes, you can propose list of "possible publications" and where you would like them to get published. Every field has some renowned conferences and journal one could possibly target. I have not read the point in full detail but based on what you mention here, it seems like the list does not need to be very concrete and concise. But you should be knowledgeable about your possible publication topics and where they would appear that could certainly be changed.
